# How do I display SQL query on a specific page of my wordpress site

Tags: sql

this is the query i want to display

**SELECT** `account_number`, `consumer_name`, `bill_amount`, `due_date`, `disco_date`, `bill_status` **FROM** `wp_bill_inquiry` **WHERE** `account_number` = *input*  **AND** `pin_number` = *input*

by inputting the data in a form like this

[image]

I hope to get this display as a result

[image]

Comment: Just for number `1234`? Or does that need to be dynamic? Important detail.

Comment: actually i want it to be dynamic. where you need to enter an account_number and a pin_number on a form before it runs the query. the account number_number and pin_number has to match or else it doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `account_number`,`consumer_name`,`bill_amount`,`due_date`,`disco_date`,`bill_status` FROM {$wpdb->prefix}_bill_inquiry where  `account_number` = '$inputnumber' AND `pin_number` = '$inputpin'", OBJECT );
```

`$wpdb->prefix` will automatically print the prefix, then to convert the result in array form you can use the following snippet:

```
$result = json_decode(json_encode($result),true);
```

You can either place it in a  template or you can create a shortcode in functions.php, you can refer [shortcode docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

Comment: thank you for answering. sorry for this novice question but, where exactly do I place this?

Comment: I updated my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: I tried placing it in a template. it just returned it as text. do I have declare anything somewhere for it to work?

Comment: Jepoy - it needs to be inside the php tags http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php  If you place it where there is straight html the yes it will appear as text.   Surround it with <?php  ........ ?> if you are puttingn it in the midst of html.

Comment: Thanks again. I already made it work. I'm facing another problem now. the account number in the database needs to be formatted like this 01-2345-6789. I can't seem to use select query because of the dash. note that account_number is one of the conditions in my query.

Comment: you can compare it by removing all the special characters from the input, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114411/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string) might help you.

Comment: I meant that the data inside the database has dashes. and when I input in the text field for the condition. it does not output anything. this is the idea of the query "SELECT * FROM wp_db WHERE account_number = 01-2345-6789"

Comment: do you want to compare exactly same, with dashes in place?

Comment: this is my exact query: "SELECT account_number, consumer_name, bill_amount, due_date, disco_date, bill_status FROM wp_bill_inquiry WHERE account_number = $account AND pin_number = $pin"; 

the account_number in the database is 01-2345-6789

but when I enter 01-2345-6789 in the text field $account it does not output anything. I'm sorry for not being able to formulate my question well.

Comment: sounds strange, have you tried running same query in phpmyadmin SQL? Is it working there?